# Buscar un registro en todas las tablas Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

actualmente estoy en la busqueda de una query o un script que me permita buscar una palabra entre todas las tablas dentro de una misma base de datos, buscando en internet consegui este codigo:

```html
CREATE PROC SearchAllTables
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
    SET  @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
            FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE   TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                        OBJECT_ID(
                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                             ), 'IsMSShipped'
                               ) = 0
        )

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName =
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                    AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                    AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                    AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
            )

            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                )
            END
        END 
    END

    SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
END
```

Pero lo ejecuto y me da error... ¿Algunos de ustedes saben si existe alguna buscar un dato entre todas las tablas?

Comment: Una palabra a nivel de información de objetos es decir: tablas, procedimientos, funciones, etc.. o en la información de la tabla, es decir, datos en las columnas?

Comment: Un registro de un campo, por ejemplo la palabra atletas, que la busque en todas las tablas de la base de datos y asi pueda ver yo en que tabla se encuentra.

Answer (score 1):

Sería algo así:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION buscarCadena(cadena character varying, esquema character varying) RETURNS 
 character varying AS $$
DECLARE
 tabla character varying;
 columna character varying;
 r record;
    BEGIN
    FOR tabla IN
        select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = esquema 
    LOOP
        FOR columna IN
            SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'public' 
                AND table_name = tabla and data_type = 'character varying'
        LOOP
            FOR r IN EXECUTE format('SELECT 1 FROM %I where %I = ''%I''', tabla,columna,cadena)
            LOOP
                return 'tabla: '|| tabla||' || columna: '||columna;
            END LOOP;

        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    return 'No encontrada';
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Así te devolvería la primera tabla+columna de coincidencia. Para llamarla sería:

```
select buscarCadena('cadena', 'public');
```

Espero te sirva, saludos!